# GridView Footer spanned columns unhides on click of Delete Button's "NO" option

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**Background:** I have a GridView binding the data through code. The grid also has Footer that shows the Total Page Count through Code. In the last column I am using CommandField Edit and Delete images for user to Edit and Delete the records (image below). On `ListOfTables_RowDataBound` of the Grid, the footer cells are getting merged and the excess cells are removed (refer Code 1).

[image]

**Code 1**

```
Protected Sub ListOfTables_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then

        Dim intCellsCount As Integer = e.Row.Cells.Count

        For i As Integer = intCellsCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(i)
        Next

        e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = intCellsCount
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Page <b>" & ListOfTables.PageIndex + 1 & "</b> of <b>" & ListOfTables.PageCount & "</b>"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Issue:** When I click on Delete button (x image), system prompts for confirmation box. When I click on "No", then the issue appears (image below) with Code 2

[image]

**Code 2**

```
Protected Sub ListOfTables_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim intTableID As Integer, strConfirmDecision As String

    strConfirmDecision = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected Table.", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirm Delete")

    If Trim(strConfirmDecision) = vbYes Then
        intTableID = ListOfTables.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        Call DeleteTableRecordFromDatabase(intTableID)
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

Protected Sub DeleteTableRecordFromDatabase(ByVal intTableID As Integer)

    Dim strConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand, intReturnVal As Integer

    Try

        'Set the Command Type as Stored Procedure to the command object
        'and pass the Stored Procedure Name as well as the Parameters needed
        objCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        objCommand.CommandText = "sp_Delete_RestaurantTable_ByTableID"
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_TableID", intTableID)
        objCommand.Connection = objConnection

        objConnection.Open()
        intReturnVal = objCommand.ExecuteScalar()

    Catch SQLEx As SqlException
        Dim objSqlError As SqlError
        Dim errMsg As New StringBuilder()

        For Each objSqlError In SQLEx.Errors
            errMsg.Append(objSqlError.Message)
        Next

        Call PrintTransactionStatus(0, TablesUpdatePanel, errMsg.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call PrintTransactionStatus(0, TablesUpdatePanel, ex.Message.ToString())
    Finally
        objCommand.Dispose()
        objConnection.Close()
        objConnection.Dispose()

        CreateAndBindGridView(ViewState("sortExp"), ViewState("sortOrder"))

        If Trim(intReturnVal) > 0 Then
            Call PrintTransactionStatus(0, TablesUpdatePanel, "There was an error while deleting the record. Please try again.")
        Else
            Call PrintTransactionStatus(1, TablesUpdatePanel, "Selected Table has been deleted successfully.")
        End If

    End Try

End Sub
```

Everything is working fine except the Column thing..Not sure where I am doing wrong..
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Although I have managed to resolve the issue by adding the column removal code again after `e.Cancel = True` in `ListOfTables_RowDeleting` procedure. The code used is   `ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells.Count  
For i As Integer = ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1  
 ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(i)  
Next`.  I am still seeking experts advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by moving the colspan into a procedure and then calling again.

```
Protected Sub ListOfTables_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim intTableID As Integer, strConfirmDecision As String

    strConfirmDecision = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected Table.", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirm Delete")

    If Trim(strConfirmDecision) = vbYes Then
        intTableID = ListOfTables.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        Call DeleteTableRecordFromDatabase(intTableID)
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
        Call ListOfTables_GridColSpan()
    End If

End Sub

Sub ListOfTables_GridColSpan()

    Dim intCellsCount As Integer = ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells.Count

    ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = intCellsCount

    For i As Integer = intCellsCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
        ListOfTables.FooterRow.Cells.RemoveAt(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a dubbuger on ListOfTables_RowDataBound event. It would be executing again while you select NO for deleting a row (means your grid would be re-populating). If this is the case, then you have to place some logic in ListOfTables_RowDataBound event only.

Comment: when I click on the Delete image, only single procedure is called and i.e., `ListOfTables_RowDeleting`. When No is chosen in the confirm box, the process ends at `e.Cancel = True`. If I am not mistaken `ListOfTables_RowDataBound` will only trigger when there is a change in the Grid Rows but I am choosing "NO" so no change in the grid.

Comment: did you try putting dubugger on the ListOfTable_RowDataBound event?

Comment: Yes, but RowDataBound will trigger while the page is loading and grid rows are forming. It will not trigger when there is a click on button with no changes to grid.

Comment: You can try one thing. Can you bind your grid on cancel event. Since your everything is working fine and only cancel event is creating issue, so you can bind your grid on this event. I know this is not a good solution but this may be a workaround for your problem (quick fix).

Comment: Thanks quick fix I have already applied after Cancel event but instead of calling to data again, I am removing the cells. See my comments under original post